# ЧПУ категории бесконечного уровня вложенности

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Подскажите как организовать чпу правильно
Есть админка где пользователь может создавать категории товаров + категории 1 + категория и тд и тп

К примеру строка будет:
my-site.ru/index.php?review=shop&cat=appliance&v-cat=kitchen&b-cat=redmond-rmc-pm330

Вывожу в браузер:

my-site.ru/shop/appliance/kitchen/redmond-rmc-pm330/

В файле .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?review=$1&cat=$2&v-cat=$3&b-cat=$4[QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?review=$1&cat=$2&v-cat=$3
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?review=$1&cat=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?review=$1
```

Как правильно написать именно в .htaccess? так так под категорий может быть больше не 2 или 3, к примеру 10, то не ужели следующая строка будет и так далее по аналогии?:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?review=$1&cat=$2&v-cat=$3&b-cat=$4&n-cat=$5[QSA,L]
```

Может есть простое решение, неужели именно так все делают?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно такие параметры не обрабатывают на уровне mod_rewrite, а отправляют все запросы на одну точку входа

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.php [L]
```

Пишут роутинг, который извлекает из переменной `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` содержимое запрашиваемой строки, вычисляет уровень вложения каталогов и в зависимости от этого рендерит нужную страницу.

Comment: Спасибо, всё понял!